# Populate a ComboBox present inside a DataGridView in windows Application using c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to populate a combobox present inside a DGV from database but its not working. My code is :-

```
    private void popParent()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sqlPS = @"SELECT * FROM tbl_acc_ledgergroup_msb";
        try
        {
            using (FbConnection conPS = new FbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conPS.Open();
                using (FbCommand cmdPS = new FbCommand(sqlPS, conPS))
                {
                    using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand = cmdPS;
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cell0=(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)(dataGridView1.Columns["Fee Head"]);
                        cell0.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].Table.DefaultView;
                        cell0.ValueMember = "lg_id";
                        cell0.DisplayMember = "lg_name";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PP-->>" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Presently the program exits without giving any error message from the line

```
cell0.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].Table.DefaultView;
```

Please advise what could be wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
cell0.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].Table.DefaultView;
```

to

```
cell0.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I have made the necessary changes as suggested by you but even then it does not work. The program exits without any error message from line :cell0.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

Comment: @gomesh mundha see my edited answer. When I check to my old code about this, I didn't use DataTable.DefaultView property as DataSource, only use DataTable objec as DataSource. And when I change use DefaultView, it doesn't fill the combobox